# How to customize the DhtmlxScheduler time period?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dhtmlx

I want to customize time period interval (such as to 00:00,00:05,00:10 ...23:55) to 1:00 2:00....12:00 in dhtmlxScheduler. Is it possible? If yes, please let me know how to do it.

Thanks,
Abi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
scheduler.config.time_step  = 60; //time step in minutes
```